# Joomla Annoying Footer

Tags: html, css, joomla, anchor

My Joomla site http://financial-freedom.com.au/ showing an annoying footer as

`<a href='http://okjoomla.com' target='_blank'>Welcome to Get more sources</a>`

I tried using dreamweaver's find tool but it didn't work. I also tried using search function in database which too didn't work.

Did anyone ever had this issue? I tried all the day Googling for this and found nothing. Any help is highly appreciated.

Edit: I manually check the footer module. And, found nothing there. As there are too many modules I can't check each module cause I believe search using Dreamweaver find too& search in PhpMyAdmin should search all modules content.

Thanks

Comment: Added CSS tag as you commented that you are open to CSS solution as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you commented, you do not have to search module in Dreamweaver or PHP MyAdmin, you will need administrator access [like](http://financial-freedom.com.au/administrator/) ... Or you will have to search in `index.php` as I told you, also I just opened that site, seems like you are downloading premium templates for free, so they do add backlinks, which are hard to figure out without source codes... So that's all I can help... Read ahead..

---

It may be a module, or the text must be literal string in your `index.php` page, if it's a module than disable it, else, go to the path below...

`root/templates/system/index.php`

In the above file, the text must be somewhere in the bottom, so just remove it

---

If you are not able to do that, than cheapest solution using CSS is `display: none;`, so as your `a` tag is adjacent to `div` having an `id` `footerwrap` so you can use

```
#footerwrap + a[href="http://okjoomla.com"] {
   display: none;
}
```

OR

```
a[href="http://okjoomla.com"] {
   display: none; /* This will remove all the anchor having that link */
}
```

Or you can use jQuery to remove it from the DOM completely

```
$('#footerwrap + a').remove();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XHdA6/1/)

Or to be more specific, and independent of the `#footerwrap`

```
$('a[href="http://okjoomla.com"]').remove();  
/* This will remove all the anchor having that link so if you are 
   sure that it will be always adjacent than use #footerwrap + as well */
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/XHdA6/)

Comment: let me try this CSS but I am afraid it may take away all footer, please check viewsource in financial-freedom.com.au and it doesn't have any div id or any inheritance to do that.

Comment: Awesome mate, I tried `a[href="http://okjoomla.com"] {
   display: none; /* This will remove all the anchor having that link */
}` and it worked for me. Great thanks.